# Questions from Dijkstra's EWD 1300: "The notational conventions I adopted, and why"

Tags: formal-methods

A link to the transcript of the manuscript: http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD13xx/EWD1300.html

My questions:

What does Dijkstra mean by:

> "Do not introduce priority [precedence] rules that destroy symmetry. I remember how
>   much more pleasant the predicate calculus became to work with after we
>   had decided to give con- and disjunction the same binding power and
>   thus to consider p ∧ q ∨ r an ill-formed formula."?

Specifically: can you illustrate how a precedence rule where conjunction has higher precedence than disjunction would destroy symmetry?

Then, what does he mean by (please note that he uses the "." operator to denote function application):

> "As time went on, I learned to appreciate expressions built with
>   operators as a way of avoiding functional notation. We can write the
>   difference  a−b  as  dif.(a, b) or exc.(b, a), where min and exc are
>   functions of an ordered pair. (I believe that the notion of “function
>   of 2 arguments” is now obsolete.) But we can also write the “curried”
>   versions (min. a). b and (sub. b). a in which, for instance, sub is a
>   higher-order function such that sub. b decreases its argument by b (so
>   that sub.(−1) would be the successor function). Functions dif, exc,
>   min and sub are different functions and as soon as the operation of
>   functional composition enters the game, the distinctions are
>   essential. But as long as we don’t do functional composition, the
>   choice between the four options is irrelevant and writing the
>   expression a−b is a lovely way of avoiding being overspecific."?

Specifically: what is the function exc, and how is it that a-b can represent both exc and min? Am I correct in understanding that min is the minimum function?

Answer (score 2):

1. Conjunction and disjunction are dual, but if conjunction has higher precedence than disjunction, then dual to p ∧ q ∨ r is (p ∨ q) ∧ r != p ∨ q ∧ r.
2. As you can see `exc` is `dif` with its arguments flipped: `exc(x, y) = y - x`. `min` is probably short for "minus", not "minimum".

Comment: Thank you, it's beginning to click for me now. min is sub with its arguments flipped, and exc is dif with its arguments flipped.

However, another question: what do you mean by "dual"?

Comment: @twirlobite See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duality_%28mathematics%29#Duality_in_logic_and_set_theory

Comment: How is the dual of  p ∧ q ∨ r then (p ∨ q) ∧ r? Are you missing negation signs?

Comment: No: "In classical logic, the ∧ and ∨ operators are dual in this sense"